# Discord.js/Mongodb How to update database values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

At the moment I am trying to update a value for the mongodb database I am working on, but I don't know how to get it to work.

Original values:

```js
await client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
    Config.findOne(
      {
        Author_Tag: message.author.tag,
      },
      (err, guild) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);

        if (!guild) {
          const newConfig = new Config({
            Author_Tag: message.author.tag,
            Clue_1: "False",
            Clue_2: "False",
            Clue_3: "False",
            Clue_4: "False",
            Clue_5: "False",
            Clue_6: "False",
            Clue_7: "False",
            Clue_8: "False",
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

Updated value after command is executed:

```js
if (command === "test") {
  client.commands.get("clue").execute(message);
  Config.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      Author_Tag: message.author.tag,
    },
    (err, guild) => {
      if (err) console.error(err);

      if (!guild) {
        const newConfig = new Config({
          Clue_1: "True",
        });

        return newConfig.save();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)'s second parameter is supposed to be the update. For example:

```js
Config.findOneAndUpdate({Author_Tag: message.author.tag}, {Clue_1: "True" })
```

---

What you are looking for is [`db.collection.findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/).

I believe the above code will work correctly if you use `db.collection.findOne()` instead of `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()`.